# Compose e-mail via URL-params (googlemail)

Tags: google-chrome, gmail

I'm working on an extension for chrome, where i need to compose gmail messages from URL. Anyone knows how i set the recipient and the subject via URL-Param?? Is there a better approach to do that or is this even possible?
Thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12979218/1739100 See the answer above for majority of the code written for you. It's setup to be a chrome extension.

Answer (score 6):

@Pekka's response is good for a general mailto, but to get a Gmail compose window pre-filled, you need to use a URL like the following : http://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&to=TO_ADDRESS@example.com&cc=CC_ADDRESS@example.com&bcc=BCC_ADDRESS@example.com&su=SUBJECT&body=BODY -- with your parameters URL-encoded.

But be careful that you don't go beyond Google's character limit or you'll get a 
"414 - Request-URI Too Large" error, as explained in this StackOverflow question: [Prefilling large volumes of body text in GMAIL compose getting a Request URI too long error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590467/prefilling-large-volumes-of-body-text-in-gmail-compose-getting-a-request-uri-too/3026185#3026185)

Answer (score 1):

To automatically **open gmail in new tab and populate the fields**:

The URL should be, `https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=example@gmail.com&su=${subject}&body=${message}`

**Example:**

```js
const subject = `${formData.fullName} - ${formData.subject}`
const message = `${formData.message}`
const mailtoLink = `https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&to=example@gmail.com&su=${subject}&body=${message}`
      window.open(mailtoLink, '_blank') // this would open gmail in new link
```

**Note**: For the subject, the query param `subject` didn't work as suggested in most of the answers, but `su` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Check [**this article**](http://email.about.com/od/mailtoemaillinks/a/mailto_elements.htm).

> mailto:recipient@example.com?subject=Hi!&body=Hi!

You can even specify headers, I didn't know that.