# How to send longer emails from a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I would like to make a Chrome extension that lets users send emails with certain text automatically filled in. I was using a `mailto:` link, but it cannot handle strings longer than 1024 characters, and it cannot create html links. Is there a way I can fill in additional text and maybe even HTML links, from within the email page (perhaps with local storage)?

Comment: 'it cannot handle strings longer than 1024 characters, and it cannot create html links'. Sounds like you answered your own question =).

Comment: But I thought there there could be an alternative to mailto. Maybe by calling localstorage from within the user's gmail page and filling in the email there?

Comment: Ah, I see. Sorry, but I don't have much experience in the area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no native chrome/javascript API to my knowledge.  I did some searching and found an open source option that someone was working on but it was very skeleton.  He was hoping others would jump on with him and flesh it out.

**Sounds like you're trying this:**

For creating the URL, you can use the &body= tag and url encode the message however there is a limit to the length.  It sounds like you already figured out how to open a new tag using chrome so you've been able to create shorter emails using nothing but a modified URL string.  I did something similar to that on my first chrome exension.  It looked something like this.

```
function sendToUrl(){ chrome.tabs.query({active:true, windowId: chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT}, function(tab) {
    //while this seems to generate the URL correctly, gmail limits how long the body text can be therefore this is not a viable solution
    //Also there is no javascript API therefore there is no hope of sending an email.

    //Need to loop through each tab and not just the first one
    var currentTab = tab[0];
    var tabInformation = RPATH.getTab(currentTab.id);

        var mailUrl = "https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&fs=1&tf=1&su=My%20Subject&to=";
        // grab the email addresss from popup.html
        mailUrl += document.getElementById("to").value + "&body=";

        // get formBody from popup.html
        var formBody = document.getElementById("body").value;
...
//I did some other stuff that isn't relevant here
...
        //Concat final mailto url
        mailUrl = mailUrl + formBody;
        chrome.extension.sendMessage({mailUrl: mailUrl}, function(response){ console.log(response.farewell);});
});}
```

**For longer email bodies**

That only gets you half way though.  The only alternative I could think of was to split up the tab open and filling out the email body.  You could modify the email body after page load completes using append.  That might look something like what I have below.  Notice I'm selecting the iframe element, then finding the body tag inside of there, and finally appending some html just after the  tag opens.  Notice the email body is nothing more then html so div, tr, br, etc tags should all work in creating a well formatted email.  In my previous example I pulled the text from the form as a string.  You could instead use jquery to clone the html on your popup.html page and append the cloned html.  For simplicity's sake, I only put text inside the append.

```
$("iframe#:1t4").find("body.editable").append('<p>My long email body</p>');
```

I suppose from there you could run a click event but you could also leave that to the user.