# Automatically open default email client and pre-populate content

Tags: javascript, mailto

I need to automatically open a user's default email client when they save some content on a page. I need to populate the email subject, to address, and put some content in the email body.

What is the best option to achieve this?

I'm aware of the `mailto:` attribute, but the user must click on this and I'm not sure it allows you to specifiy the subject and content?

Comment: You can set each and every part of an email in a mailto-prefixed href. Here's a tool I built to make it dead simple: mailto.now.sh

Comment: You can follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/78233816/10824697

Answer (score 173, accepted):

As described by [RFC 6068](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6068), mailto allows you to specify *subject* and *body*, as well as *cc* fields. For example:

```
mailto:username@example.com?subject=Subject&body=message%20goes%20here
```

User doesn't need to click a link if you [force it to be opened with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868315/invoke-click-a-mailto-link-with-jquery-javascript)

```
window.location.href = "mailto:user@example.com?subject=Subject&body=message%20goes%20here";
```

Be aware that there is no single, standard way in which browsers/email clients handle mailto links (e.g. subject and body fields may be discarded without a warning). Also there is a risk that popup and ad blockers, anti-virus software etc. may silently block forced opening of mailto links.

Comment: Is there a way to load the image (not the url, but the actual image) into the message with jQuery?

Comment: What if the message passes the character limit? It's a nice workaround but it doesn't seem to be an elegant solution.

Comment: What if I need to add some other content as example image, css or html

Comment: Is it possible to sent attachment with the above details ?

Comment: If it passes character limit, you could use encodeURIComponent(body). 
But still the length of the email body may still be limited by the email client or the recipient's email service

Answer (score 21):

**JQuery:**

```
$(function () {
      $('.SendEmail').click(function (event) {
        var email = 'sample@gmail.com';
        var subject = 'Test';
        var emailBody = 'Hi Sample,';
        var attach = 'path';
        document.location = "mailto:"+email+"?subject="+subject+"&body="+emailBody+
            "?attach="+attach;
      });
    });
```

**HTML:**

```
 <button class="SendEmail">Send Email</button>
```

Comment: how to send html content by this way

Answer (score 6):

Implemented this way without using Jquery:

```
<button class="emailReplyButton" onClick="sendEmail(message)">Reply</button>

function sendEmail(message) {
    var email = message.emailId;
    var subject = message.subject;
    var emailBody = 'Hi '+message.from;
    document.location = "mailto:"+email+"?subject="+subject+"&body="+emailBody;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Try this:**
It will open the default mail directly.

```
<a href="mailto:demo@demo.com"><img src="ICON2.png"></a>
```