# How to create an email button with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, email

I couldn't find a post that really matches my question, so here we go:

I want to implement a "share via mail" button to my website, so when you click the button let's say outlook or thunderbird opens and gives you the option to share the website link within a new mail.

I'm not quite sure but I think I won't be able to do it completely with html only, cause facebook i.e. is also running JSs when you link to their share-site.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web-based_protocol_handlers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automically open default email client and pre-populate content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231125/automically-open-default-email-client-and-pre-populate-content)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need javascript for this. Just a simple **HTML**:

```
<a id="emailMe" href="mailto:example@website.com">e-mail me</a>
```

You can also define a *subject* but you must remember that you can only use characters a-z and numbers 0-9. Other characters must be url-encoded, e.g. subject "This is a subject" should be encoded like this

```
<a id="emailMe" href="mailto:example@website.com?subject=This%20is%20a%20subject">e-mail me</a>
```

If you don't want to manually encode each character which is pretty obvious, here comes javascript finally:

```
var subject = "This is a subject";
var subjectEncoded = encodeURIComponent(subject);
document.getElementById('emailMe').href = "mailto:example@website.com?subject=" + subjectEncoded;
```

Comment: You can also specify the message using the 'body' attribute.

Answer (score 6):

here you go:

```
<a href="mailto:mail@address.com?subject=just-a-subject">Send a mail</a>
```

hope it helped.

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="mailto:?Subject=SubjectHere&body=ThisIsTheMailtext">
```

Why would you use javascript? Now it opens and you have to put the recipient in /its empty).

Answer (score 3):

email link with js

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var aTag = document.createElement('a');
aTag.setAttribute('href',"mailto:me@mail.com?subject=Subject&body=message%20goes%20here");
aTag.innerHTML = "share via mail";
mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
```