# Java desktop mail is not working

Tags: java, awt

I have deployed one of my web application in tomcat on remote machine.

while, before deploying i have implemented `Desktop.getDesktop().mail` functionality to invoke outlook email in my local system.

I have successfully invoked the outlook email.

The problem is when deployed the same in to remote machine in tomcat and trying to access the webapp from my client machine. I could not able to invoke outlook mail application.

Is there any problem, does any one faced the same problem before?

Answer (score 1):

Because `Desktop.getDesktop().mail` api is for launching your native desktop application. when you run webapp, there is only javascript/html at client side. your `Desktop.getDesktop().mail` api will be invoked on your server where webapp is deployed.

If you want to open native email application at your client side, then use javascript. Please see link below.

[Automatically open default email client and pre-populate content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231125/automically-open-default-email-client-and-pre-populate-content)