# Dial email in Html

Tags: html, email

I am trying to dial the email in HTML. But it is not working.

```
<div>
    <a href="mail:testingmail@gmail.com"
    mail="testingmail@gmail.com">testingmail@gmail.com</a>
 </div>
```

I have tried this. Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Automatically open default email client and pre-populate content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231125/automatically-open-default-email-client-and-pre-populate-content)

Comment: Sir, I tried to find the solution but by that time I did not find any. Because the question is different.
But yes, If I would get this before I could have solved it. Thank you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You must use `mailto:` instead of `mail:`:

```
<div>
    <a href="mailto:testingmail@gmail.com" mail="testingmail@gmail.com">testingmail@gmail.com</a>
</div>
```